# How to force clicking on "Refresh" link button after saving some data into DB , by javascript?

Tags: javascript, webforms, refresh

I'm completely newbie in JavaScript. Now my problem is:
I have a page (Default.aspx). The page has a link button "Refresh" (lbtnRefresh) and another linkbutton (lbtnSave) which saves some data users has entered into DB.

I want the page be refreshed after saving data into DB, by using javascript.

Is that possible or not?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following function:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

The `true` argument will force the browser to bypass the cache and reload from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it by changing the current window location

```
window.location = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/?timestamp=6546546416';
```

To avoid cache, you can add a timestamp to the url.

Comment: That will add each refresh to the browser history, though.